# Should a question that is very similar to one previously asked be immediately marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

If a user (particularly those who are new to the site) asked a question which was very similar to a question previously asked, would it be better to first **ask** the user to check if the solution posted in the similar question helped **before** it gets immediately marked as a duplicate?

On a couple of occassions, I marked a question as duplicate only for it to be reopened because the solutions did not help the OP.

*I think this is more targeted to moderators and high-rep users as they can immediately mark such questions.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)

> The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people
>   find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.

I prefer marking as Duplicate early, and then reopening if it doesn't meet the askers requirement.  I think most of what we mark as duplicate is accurate, and even many where the asker disagrees it comes down to how they're read/understood the answer in the earlier question and how to apply it to their situation.

[How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

> *Questions may be duplicates if they have the **same (potential) answers**. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.*

It is easy enough to open again if further comment/explanation/clarification shows that it is not a duplicate.  As a community I believe we are fairly quick to reopen when necessary.

If we delay while waiting for confirmation then we end up with answers from others, and Q&A duplication.

I would like to think that moderators and other reviewers actually do take the time to review the questions before they make a decision, rather than just closing without thought.  The reopening process can be as quick as the closing process. An edit to a question goes into the review queue - the question itself doesn't need to be generating that steady flow of traffic to get the votes.

Sometimes people get it wrong, or the original asker is getting a different result as seen in the duplicated question, and the only way to know that is for additional information to be added to clarify. This is where a user genuinely believes the question is duplicated, and I see no problem with marking that as a duplicate. If you are unsure you can always request clarification first.

If you see something that you think is not a duplicate, hit the Reopen or Flag to put it in a queue, and add a comment.

Also in [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

> **Someone says the question is a duplicate, but I disagree!**
>
> Questions may be similar without being exact duplicates:
>
> [From the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/):
>
> > There could be hundreds of different, related, perfectly valid questions on the same topic. There is no One True Question.
>
> and...
>
> > It's rarely this straightforward, however -- usually there are two similar but not-quite-the-same questions, both of which have value for
> >     different reasons.
>
> If you think a question is related, but not a duplicate, it's a good
>   idea to edit the question to add a note explaining the difference. You
>   can use wording like
>
> > Unlike What color is the sky on Titan?, I'm asking about a planet rotating around a brown dwarf.
>
> If you're the author, edit your question to explain how it differs. If
>   you see the question in the [close review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work), you can vote to leave
>   open. If the question is closed and you have the privilege to [vote to
>   close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you can vote to reopen it.